# Running Flyway on Command Line doesn't find SpringJdbcMigrations

Tags: java, database-migration, flyway

I'm trying to set up a process where we run Flyway from the command line to run our migrations (due to some restrictions put on my by my DBAs)

I have this working nicely for the most part, finding and running SQL and normal JdbcMigrations, but it won't recognize my SpringJdbcMigrations, claiming that it doesn't have Spring Jdbc available.

Below, find my file structure, properties, and debug output from flyway:

File Structure
[image: File Structure]

flyway.properties

```
#
# License removed for brevity

# Jdbc url to use to connect to the database
flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_project

# User to use to connect to the database (default: <<null>>)
flyway.user=root

# Password to use to connect to the database (default: <<null>>)
flyway.password=XXXXXXX

# Comma-separated list of locations to scan recursively for migrations. (default: filesystem:<<INSTALL-DIR>>/sql)
# The location type is determined by its prefix.
# Unprefixed locations or locations starting with classpath: point to a package on the classpath and may contain both sql and java-based migrations.
# Locations starting with filesystem: point to a directory on the filesystem and may only contain sql migrations.
flyway.locations=classpath:com.mycompany.myproject.db.migration,filesystem:sql

# NOTE: All other properties are left as default
```

Debug output:

```
[localhost ~/Documents/ws-src/flyway-3.0] ./flyway migrate -X
/usr/bin/tput
Flyway (Command-line Tool) v.3.0

DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: /Users/biggusjimmus/Documents/ws-src/flyway-3.0/bin/../jars/java-migration.jar
DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: /Users/biggusjimmus/Documents/ws-src/flyway-3.0/bin/../jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
#
# NOTE: This library SHOULD enable Spring Jdbc, as far as I know.
#
DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: /Users/biggusjimmus/Documents/ws-src/flyway-3.0/bin/../jars/spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproject (MySQL 5.6)
DEBUG: DDL Transactions Supported: false
DEBUG: Schema: myproject
#
#NOTE: spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar was apparently added to the classpath above!
#
DEBUG: Spring Jdbc available: false
DEBUG: Spring Jdbc available: false
DEBUG: Validating migrations ...
DEBUG: Scanning for classpath resources at 'com/mycompany/myproject/db/migration' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql')
DEBUG: Scanning URL: jar:file:/Users/biggusjimmus/Documents/ws-src/flyway-3.0/bin/../jars/java-migration.jar!/com/mycompany/myproject/db/migration
DEBUG: JBoss VFS v2 available: false
DEBUG: Filtering out resource: com/mycompany/myproject/db/migration/ (filename: )
DEBUG: Filtering out resource: com/mycompany/myproject/db/migration/V1_1_4_2__Java_Spring_Example.class (filename: V1_1_4_2__Java_Spring_Example.class)
DEBUG: Filtering out resource: com/mycompany/myproject/db/migration/V1_1_4_3__Java_NoSpring_Example.class (filename: V1_1_4_3__Java_NoSpring_Example.class)
DEBUG: Scanning for classes at 'com/mycompany/myproject/db/migration' (Implementing: 'org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration')
DEBUG: Scanning URL: jar:file:/Users/biggusjimmus/Documents/ws-src/flyway-3.0/bin/../jars/java-migration.jar!/com/mycompany/myproject/db/migration
DEBUG: JBoss VFS v2 available: false
DEBUG: Filtering out resource: com/mycompany/myproject/db/migration/ (filename: )
#
# NOTE: Why did it find the NoSpring example (which implements JdbcMigration), 
# but not the spring example (which implements SpringJdbcMigration), even though 
# it's in the same package? 
# Presumably because it doesn't think it has Spring Jdbc support
#
DEBUG: Found class: com.mycompany.myproject.db.migration.V1_1_4_3__Java_NoSpring_Example
DEBUG: Scanning for filesystem resources at 'sql' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql')
DEBUG: Scanning for resources in path: sql (sql)
DEBUG: Filtering out resource: sql/.DS_Store (filename: .DS_Store)
DEBUG: Found filesystem resource: sql/V1_1_3__Base_version.sql
DEBUG: Found filesystem resource: sql/V1_1_4_1__SQL_Example.sql
Validated 3 migrations (execution time 00:00.052s)
DEBUG: Schema `myproject` already exists. Skipping schema creation.
DEBUG: Locking table `myproject`.`schema_version`...
DEBUG: Lock acquired for table `myproject`.`schema_version`
Current version of schema `myproject`: 1.1.3
Migrating schema `myproject` to version 1.1.4.1
DEBUG: Successfully completed and committed migration of schema `myproject` to version 1.1.4.1
DEBUG: MetaData table `myproject`.`schema_version` successfully updated to reflect changes
DEBUG: Locking table `myproject`.`schema_version`...
DEBUG: Lock acquired for table `myproject`.`schema_version`
Migrating schema `myproject` to version 1.1.4.3
DEBUG: Successfully completed and committed migration of schema `myproject` to version 1.1.4.3
DEBUG: MetaData table `myproject`.`schema_version` successfully updated to reflect changes
DEBUG: Locking table `myproject`.`schema_version`...
DEBUG: Lock acquired for table `myproject`.`schema_version`
Successfully applied 2 migrations to schema `myproject` (execution time 00:00.049s).
```

If there's any other information i can provide that may be helpful, please let me know.

EDIT:
I also tried modifying the shell shell script to add the spring-jdbc jar to its classpath directly.  Running with that modification caused no apparent change.

Running with that change (on top of the updated database, and without the debug flag) produced this result:

```
[localhost ~/Documents/ws-src/flyway-3.0] sh -x flyway migrate
++ pwd
+ OLDDIR=/Users/biggusjimmus/Documents/ws-src/flyway-3.0
+ PRG=flyway
+ '[' -h flyway ']'
++ dirname flyway
+ INSTALLDIR=.
+ cd .
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ JAVA_CMD=java
+ command -v tput
/usr/bin/tput
++ tput cols
+ CONSOLE_WIDTH=116
+ java -cp ./bin/flyway-commandline-3.0.jar:./bin/flyway-core-3.0.jar:./jars/spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar org.flywaydb.commandline.Main migrate -consoleWidth=116
Flyway (Command-line Tool) v.3.0

Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproject (MySQL 5.6)
Validated 3 migrations (execution time 00:00.052s)
Current version of schema `myproject`: 1.1.4.3
Schema `myproject` is up to date. No migration necessary.
+ JAVA_EXIT_CODE=0
+ cd /Users/biggusjimmus/Documents/ws-src/flyway-3.0
+ exit 0
```

Comment: I also filed an issue with flyway, in case this is a bug instead of a configuration issue: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/783

Comment: See my comment on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a way to make it work, but it requires modification of the classpath in the "flyway" shell script, which seems dubious, and also requires the inclusion of FIVE dependencies, without which I either get the behavior described in the issue, or a ClassNotFoundException.

Specifically, I need to add the following libraries to the jars directory:

- commons-logging
- spring-beans
- spring-core
- spring-jdbc
- spring-tx

And change https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/flyway-3.0/flyway-commandline/src/main/assembly/flyway#L52 to

```
"$JAVA_CMD" -cp ./bin/flyway-commandline-${project.version}.jar:./bin/flyway-core-${project.version}.jar:./jars/* org.flywaydb.commandline.Main $@ -consoleWidth=$CONSOLE_WIDTH
```

or in 4.0,  https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-commandline/src/main/assembly/flyway#L57 to

```
CP="./bin/flyway-commandline-${project.version}.jar:./bin/flyway-core-${project.version}.jar:./jars/*"
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?  Is this documented anywhere?